# Can React Native Track Player be used alongside React Native Video for displaying music notifications and controls?

Tags: react-native, audio-player, react-native-video, react-native-track-player

i am using `react-native-music-control` for  displaying music notification but because of "no longer maintained" some functionality are not working like seek bar not working etc.,

if anyone have code sample or any example for displaying music notifications using rn-track-player for React Native Video! please provide !

This is my old code where i am using react-native-music-control :-

```
import MusicControl, {Command} from 'react-native-music-control';

const notificationControl = () => {
    if (IsOfflineMode === false) {
      MusicControl.setNowPlaying({
        title: title,
        artwork: thumbnail,
        artist: author,
        colorized: true,
        isLiveStream: IsLive,
      });
      MusicControl.enableControl('play', true);
      MusicControl.enableControl('pause', true);
      MusicControl.enableControl('previousTrack', true);
      MusicControl.enableControl('nextTrack', true);
      MusicControl.enableControl('changePlaybackPosition', true);
      MusicControl.handleAudioInterruptions(true);
      MusicControl.enableControl('seekForward', false);
    }
  };

  MusicControl.on(Command.pause, () => {
    setIsPlaying(true);
  });

  MusicControl.on('play', () => {
    setIsPlaying(false);
  });

  MusicControl.on(Command.nextTrack, () => {
    newProcess('plus');
  });

  MusicControl.on(Command.previousTrack, () => {
    newProcess('subt');
  });
```